# Merging to Stored Procedures, one to many

Tags: sql

so I am not sure what I want can be done but here goes... I have two stored proceedures... one counts the amount of free time a person has to work per day and puts the record set in a temp table for speed... the results are as, fields being Date, PersonID, Hours, Minutes.

```
2013-04-03  10000305    8   30
2013-05-03  10000305    8   30
```

Within their working day they complete calls, each call has a duration recorded. My second SP works out the time they actually worked during that day. Results are as follows, fields are the same, Date, Person, Hours, Minutes.

```
2013-04-25  10000305    7   20
2013-04-26  10000305    11  7
```

The problem: I have to call two SP's and then organise. What I was hoping was that I could put all into one SP and Just have a summary which would look like the below. The problem is the second SP counts many many records during one day to get its Sum, whereas the first SP is just one day and a duration. When I tried to add together my results went crazy and bought back millions of records. Is there a simple way or is it not possible?

```
**Date**    **User**   **Hours**    **Minutes**  **Actual Hours**   **Act Mins**
2013-04-25  10000305    8            30           11                    7
```

Here is a code snippet, both are very similar in how they work

```
CREATE TABLE #TotalUsedTime 
  (PersonID Int, 
  [Date] DateTime,
  Office Int, 
  [Hours] Int, 
  [Minutes] Int)

    DECLARE @GetUsedTime NVARCHAR(MAX);
        SET @GetUsedTime = N'
Select  PersonID, [Date], Office, TotalUsedTime / 3600 AS Hours, (TotalUsedTime % 3600) / 60 AS Minutes
     From 
( Select  PersonID, [Date], Office, DateDiff(Second, Starttime, End) AS TotalUsedTime From Calls Where Completed IS NOT NULL)  x '

        INSERT #TotalUsedTime EXEC SP_Executesql @GetUsedTime;

        Select Cast([Date] as date) Date, #TotalUsedTime.PersonID,
        Cast(sum([hours] * 60 + [minutes])/60 as int) As Hours,
        Sum([hours] * 60 + [minutes]) - 60 * cast(sum([hours] * 60 + [minutes])/60 as int) As Minutes,
        People.Fullname
        From #TotalUsedTime
        Inner Join People on People.PersonID = #TotalUsedTime.PersonID
        Where #TotalUsedTime.[Date] Between @StartDate and @EndDate and Office = @Office
        and People.PersonID = @PersonID 
        Group by cast([DATE] as Date), #TotalUsedTime.PersonID, People.FullName]

        End
```

Comment: Just returnboth result sets to two different #temp tables, and then join them on Date and User to get your final result set.

Comment: if possible post your snippets. This is not so informatvie

Comment: It sounds like you might be missing join conditions on the Date and User fields.  If you don't include join conditions to connect the matching records in each table, you will get a cartesian join that returns one record for **every** combination of records in the joined tables, and that could easily run into the millions.

Comment: I think its the joins, everything checks out OK, then as soon as I add the join in as below to include the second table my results go hay wire... 

Select DISTINCT AT.[Date], AT.Fullname, AT.[Hours], AT.[Minutes] From #OrganisedAvailableTime AT 

 Join #OrganisedAvailableUsed UT On AT.[Date] = UT.[Date]

Where At.[Date] Between StartDate and EndDate and At.Usercode = @UserCode